# Animating .scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click, I trigger `.scrollTop` and it seems to work. But page goes up/down directly. How to animate this? So user can really understand whats happening.
I need to animate this piece of code: `jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery(".tabs").offset().top);`

**Whole Java Script:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
   jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(400).siblings().slideUp(400); 

   console.log(currentAttrValue);
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery(".tabs").offset().top);
    jQuery(".tab-links li").removeClass("active");
    jQuery('a[href="'+currentAttrValue+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
    </ul>  

    <div class="tab-content">

        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
                 <div id="lipsum">Long content</div>
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
                 <div id="lipsum">Long content</div>
        </div> 

    </div>

    <div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/4m2ut16k/12/

Comment: Tip: You can write `$(...)` instead of `jQuery(...)`, thats way more comfortable ;)

Answer (score 4):

use jquery animate method for animation effect.

```
jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(1000,function() {
       jQuery(this).animate({opacity: '0.5'});
}).siblings().slideUp(1000,function(){
    jQuery(this).animate({opacity: '0.5'});   
});
```

Live link http://jsfiddle.net/4m2ut16k/12/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) like,

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({ // html,body not window
                 'scrollTop':jQuery(".tabs").offset().top
           },1000); //1000 is duration here
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/4m2ut16k/13/)

Update if the tabs already visible then animate only like,

```
// Show/Hide Tabs, if visible then animate
if (jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).is(':visible')) {
  jQuery('html,body').animate({
       'scrollTop': 0  // scroll to 0 to make it consistent for both tabs
  }, 1000);
} else {
   jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(400)
                                      .siblings().slideUp(400);
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/4m2ut16k/15/)

Another updated, you need to check the height of siblings with the current one and then check for scroll top position like,

```
var $curr=jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue),
    $sib=jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings();
// Show/Hide Tabs, slidedown then animate       

if($curr.height() < $sib.height()){
    if(jQuery('html,body').scrollTop() == 0){
        $curr.slideDown(400).siblings().slideUp(400);
    } else {
        jQuery('html,body').animate({
            'scrollTop': 0
        }, 1000);
        $curr.show().siblings().hide();
    }     

} else {        
    $curr.slideDown(400,function(){
        jQuery('html,body').animate({
            'scrollTop': 0
        }, 1000);
    }).siblings().slideUp(400);
}
```

Another [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/4m2ut16k/18/)

Comment: Thank you it's working. But there is some issue. Let's say I will jump from tab2 to tab1 from bottom-side-tabs. If tab2's content is longer than tab1's, page goes down firstly and goes up after. here I tried to explain [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4m2ut16k/14/) Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It is because of `jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(400).siblings().slideUp(400);`

Comment: but without them tabs rejecting to change the content. and I found out someone who has the same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131325/jquery-scroll-to-top-with-animate-jumps-to-bottom-first) couldn't apply it to my code though.

Comment: it's all about rest of the page. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4m2ut16k/16/) Right now it doesn't scroll up at all from tab2 to tab1 when you click bottom side tabs.

Comment: Thanks for all help friend, but we unfortunately can't prevent to script visit the bottom of the page first. Still same. do you think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14136029/5153292) can be helpful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88477/discussion-between-rohan-kumar-and-rough).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method of JQuery  also check this example `**jsFiddle:**` http://jsfiddle.net/gxkuS/176/